# How do I tally votes in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got a database table called `votes` with three columns 'timestamp', 'voter', and 'voted_for'.

Each entry in the table represents one vote. I want to tally all of the votes for each 'voted_for' with some conditions.

The conditions are as follows:

- Each voter can vote only once, in the case of multiple votes by a single voter the most recent vote counts.
- Only votes made before a specified time are counted.

Comment: Your criteria don't make complete sense. How do you want to tally votes? Are you doing a simple count or otherwise? If it's simply a count, then it doesn't make sense why you need the most recent from a voter rather than just counting a voter once.

Comment: @Alison: As I understand it, a user could have changed their vote, so the OP wants to get whatever they voted for last. @johndbritton: Why can't you just re-use the same row when the user updates his vote instead of creating a new one? That way, the user's vote is always up-to-date.

Comment: @musicfreak, you're exactly right. I could have updated the row, but for the sake of simplicity I just recorded every vote. I thought it would be interesting to be able to see who changed their vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT voted_for, count(*)
FROM votes v
INNER JOIN (SELECT Voter, Max(timestamp) as lastTime from votes group by Voter) A 
on A.Voter = v.voter and a.lasttime = v.timestamp 
WHERE timestamp < {date and time of last vote allowed}
Group by voted_for
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks about right although I'm getting an error "#1054 - Unknown column 'a.lasttime' in 'on clause'."

Comment: maybe because the alias is A and the a.lasttime is lower case...i always forget about MySQL's case sensitivity!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT voted_for,COUNT(DISTINCT voter)
FROM votes
WHERE timestamp < '2010-11-18 21:05:00'
GROUP BY voted_for
```

Comment: That's close, but I don't think it's totally correct. The query needs to make sure to count the latest vote by voters that voted more than once. Your query makes sure to count only one vote by each voter but doesn't make sure it's the latest vote.

Comment: Why not just make it so that a user who votes more than once simply overwrites their existing vote instead of creating a 2nd entry to reduce the number of rows in the database?

Comment: @Leslie That's what he wanted: "all of the votes for each 'voted_for'".

Comment: @johndbritton Maybe I didn't get your requirement... if it only counts one vote per voted_for, it doesn't matter *which* vote is counted. As you don't need any date from that particular vote, it's not a greatest-n-per-group problem.

Comment: @webnet I could have updated the rows, but I didn't partially because I wanted to keep the data to see who changed votes and partially because I'm lazy.

Comment: @andrekr It should count only one vote per voter, the most resent vote to be precise. I need a tally of the number of votes for each voted_for.

Comment: @johndbritton Sorry, I don't get it. When you are *counting* only one vote, what difference does it make if you count the oldest, the most recent or any vote inbetween? They all lead to the same result: 1 (one)

Comment: @andrekr You have the ability to vote for a different result. If the first time you voted_for "1" but the second time you voted_for "2" then it matters which vote you count.

Comment: Ah, *now* I understand. I did not update my answer but instead gave Leslies +1 because it's the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

the following may prove helpful:

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users
( 
user_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
username varbinary(32) not null,
unique key users_username_idx(username)
)engine=innodb;

insert into users (username) values 
('f00'),('foo'),('bar'),('bAr'),('bish'),('bash'),('bosh');

drop table if exists picture;
create table picture
( 
picture_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
user_id int unsigned not null, -- owner of the picture, the user who uploaded it
tot_votes int unsigned not null default 0, -- total number of votes 
tot_rating int unsigned not null default 0, -- accumulative ratings 
avg_rating decimal(5,2) not null default 0, -- tot_rating / tot_votes
key picture_user_idx(user_id)
)engine=innodb;

insert into picture (user_id) values 
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(1),(1),(2),(3),(6),(7),(7),(5);


drop table if exists picture_vote;
create table picture_vote
( 
picture_id int unsigned not null,
user_id int unsigned not null,-- voter
rating tinyint unsigned not null default 0, -- rating 0 to 5
primary key (picture_id, user_id)
)engine=innodb;

delimiter #

create trigger picture_vote_before_ins_trig before insert on picture_vote
for each row
proc_main:begin

declare total_rating int unsigned default 0;
declare total_votes int unsigned default 0;

 if exists (select 1 from picture_vote where 
    picture_id = new.picture_id and user_id = new.user_id) then
        leave proc_main;
 end if;

 select tot_rating + new.rating, tot_votes + 1 into total_rating, total_votes 
  from picture where picture_id = new.picture_id;

 -- counts/stats
 update picture set 
    tot_votes = total_votes,
    tot_rating = total_rating,
    avg_rating = total_rating / total_votes
 where picture_id = new.picture_id;

end proc_main #

delimiter ;

insert into picture_vote (picture_id, user_id, rating) values 
(1,1,5),(1,2,3),(1,3,3),(1,4,2),(1,5,1), 
(2,1,1),(2,2,2),(2,3,3),(2,4,4),(2,5,5),(2,6,1),(2,7,2),
(3,1,5),(3,2,5),(3,3,5),(3,4,5),(3,5,5),(3,6,5),(3,7,5);

select * from users order by user_id;
select * from picture order by picture_id;
select * from picture_vote order by picture_id, user_id;
```

Comment: use a trigger and tally as you insert vs. hmmmm select count.. inner join... 10 million rows later - yawn.

Comment: I'm not going to vote this up, because I don't think it's the best answer.  But it's certainly helpful from the perspective of presenting a different and perfectly valid way to do what the questioner wants.